# Why doesn't decrementing an argument in a function invocation work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, splice

In a JavaScript project I was looping through a list and sometimes removing the current element with `splice()`. Now after that obviously the iterating variable need be decremented to not miss an element. Looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) { 
  if (...){
    list.splice(i,1); 
    --i
  }
}
```

Now, coming from Java, I figured I'd save a line by decrementing the variable after passing it as an argument like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) { 
  if (...)
    list.splice(i--,1)
}
```

The answers show that it should work.
The issue happened using paper.js - I opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1450) for that. It seems that paper.js was decrementing `i` before passing its value to `splice()` resulting in an actual call of `splice(-1,1)`. With an index of -1, `splice()` would remove the list's last item. On the next loop iteration, i would be incemented back to 0, the check on `list[0]` would still evaluate to `true` as the element is still there, the same call `splice(-1,1)` would happen deleting the last element, and so on.

See the broken behavior [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/XVI9b8IwEP0rVpaaEqx06FBoJ6ouXSp1BAZjLviEYyPHJG1R/nvPCQ60Sy6+9+GXp5wzKyvI5tnnAYLSWZ4pt4vnRnqm0CsDNXthq81ibde2PFkV0Fnm7Dt8v7rWcmjAhgk7ExyippJfHw5tIJGFlvXvvEFoRY0/IFrcBZ2z60ID7nWYLJLeS7tzVbLopxh2/Eo6XuDxsvtb3UijAMv+E1IYGbQYNry3yNljUUwifaSKEo1ZOuM8ie62RqrDXW94KUMcT7XmIz1m6v5V8+ap0ksx1AtjpfM85kGyLBY0nlO1woDdB0276XTgsgStcCNqJSlqIZ7iNRHDkt/A0oMkr4ek/KP1ULkGeFKOmKiPBhVwnM1ykg5oFwc9OvoBtuR66Oups/lq0/0C): Tapping keys creates circles which shrink and, when below area 1, are removed from canvas and the array holding them. The issue happens when splice() gets called in line 17.

Quite curious, that issue - thanks for the help!

Comment: "Could that be because in java" no. They are two separate languages.

Comment: Those 2 chunks look like they ought to be functionally identical

Comment: I've answered this incorrectly twice now. Before I take up farming instead of programming, could someone please answer this correctly?!

Comment: I don't believe this is a dupe - the OP is asking why these two snippets behave differently, not how to remove elements from a list.

Comment: @DenysSéguret - The OP is expecting the snippets to be equivalent (and so do I ;), hence the question.

Comment: Can you add a concrete test case?  I can't reproduce the behaviour (for at least a simple case).

Comment: I second that, would really like to see a testcase. For me it works fine too.

Comment: @DenysSéguret You are confused and misunderstand the question. He is asking how/if the rules for evaluation of the postincrement operator differ in between the languages.

Comment: Another "can't repro" here, unless I'm misunderstanding the question: https://jsfiddle.net/b91m1o9s/2/  results appear to be identical.

Comment: @Michel, you can add a JS snippet by editing your question to show the problem. Alternatively, make a jsbin or similar and link to the snippet. As Daniel shows, we have a hard time seeing a difference.

Comment: Javascript does have types, they are implicit (i.e. 'Number' which is really a float). Also, what browser/engine? This may be related to a specific engine's optimizations.

Comment: It has to do with exceeding the boundary of the array. it is caused by executing more iterations that there are array elements. Why? because the array size is being reduced within the iteration. The error is masked because of the way `array.prototype.splice works`. if the index exceeds the length of the array - it deletes everything to the end of the array.

Comment: @RandyCasburn That does not quite make sense to me. If it deletes everything to the end, from which starting point? The index that is already greater than the length? Then it would not delete anything (which is exactly what happens if you give slice an index larger than the largest valid index of that array and 1 as length).
E.g.: `var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; list.splice(7,1);` would return an empty array and leave the list untouched. Maybe I am misunderstanding you though.

Comment: I mis-stated that - if > length of the array, it sets the start parameter "to the end of the array". Sorry

Comment: My answer below don't addressed your question Michel?

Comment: In your case the decrement operator is used as a postfix (`i--`), so it returns the current value before decrementing. Which makes equivalent both alternatives used in your questions.

Comment: I had the issue using paper.js. It was in the paperscript, the list would be traversed through and eventually spliced on any "repainting of the frame" (repeatedly in fixed intervals), while items would be added to the array on any keydown event. I'm working on a test case without paper.js now, I'll update my question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference between two ways (decrementing `i` argument on `splice` call or in the next line) because you are using a post-decrement operator.

By post-decrement I mean when the `--` operator is used as a postfix (i.e. `i--`): in this case it returns the current value before decrementing. And, that's why both alternatives used in your questions are equivalents.

Regarding to type of `i` variable, you can check with `typeof` operator. In this case is a `number` object, which belongs to the scalar primitive group (`Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `undefined`, `null`, `Symbol`). All primitive values are assigned by value. Only compound values in javascript are assigned by reference (`Object`, `Array`).

You can read more about javascript [arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

Check the outputs for the two cases:

```js
function test(list, condition) {
    const list1 = [...list];
    for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      if (condition(list1[i], i)) {
        list1.splice(i--, 1);
      }
    }
    console.log('output using decrement on splice arg', list1);
    
    const list2 = [...list];
    for (var i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
      if (condition(list2[i], i)) {
        list2.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
    console.log('output decrementing after splice', list2);
}

const list = [1, 2, 3, 4];

test(list, (elem, index) => elem % 2 === 0);
// -> [1, 3]
// -> [1, 3]

test(list, (elem, index) => index % 2 !== 0);
// -> [1]
// -> [1]
```

---

The problem I see with your code is with the `if` condition inside the loop. If your test includes the index in some way that could cause you to remove extra elements (not intended in the first place).

Second example, using use a condition based on the element indexes, and  exemplifies a possible situation when we try to remove all elements on odd positions. This happens because on the second iteration (`i=1`) the tests evaluates to `true` and the decrement of `i--` steps back to zero (`i=0`). Then the `for` increment acts and again we are testing the previous scenario: `i=1`.

Previous behavior remains the same whether you decrement the iteration variable inline in the `splice` call or after.

Comment: This doesn't address the question being asked, though.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I just update the answer including the test with both ways of decrementing the `i` variable. Cheers!

Comment: I also stated that using decrement operator as a postfix is equivalent with perform the call first, and then decrement the variable.

Comment: Thank you for the swift and helpful reply! I had the problem in paperscript, where the list would be checked on any "repainting of the frame", that is to say, repeatedly. I'm trying to build an example without paperscript now to see if I can show what happens. Your code works for me too.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote / select my answer as it useful. Let me know when you build the new example (probably link to new question) to check and see what can I help with. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I upvoted but alas, it doesn't change the score because I have too few points to be meaningful yet... but I set it as helpful. Thank you for explaining how the types work and how the number is assigned by value. Must've been a different problem... Probably adding to and removing from the array while it's looping made it remove the wrong items.